# Firebase's Google Authentication User Object returns profile path with 404 response

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-authentication, google-signin

Am using Firebase Google Authentication in my App. If the user does not have a profile image, Google used to return a dynamic picture, made up from the user's first or last initial, or digraph where applicable, all depending on each person's name structure.

> Eg : If the user name is Jack and he does not have profile picture the
>   URL will return this image.

[image]

> But Past few weeks the Url Returned by the method
>   `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl();` is a 404
>   page.

[image]

Because of this am getting Exceptions in Glide app. I need an image as above as my App is a conversation app, Which will help users to identify easily if they dont have a profile image. Please let me know if google changed the way accessing the image or it stopped permanently. Also provide me any alternatives to get this above image.